# onload event inside iframe only triggers once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

I have a **cross-domain** iframe inside one of my page, its content should use the `window.parent.postMessage` method to notify  it is rendered to the containing page (so it can adjust iframe's height to its content). It works quite well, but only once, if I start clicking in the iframe and browsing different pages, the load event does not get triggered anymore even if all the pages in the iframe contains the same JavaScript code (see below).

here's the container's code let's say **container.js**:

```
function onMessage(jqEvent) {
    if (jqEvent.originalEvent.data.iframe) {
        var iframeContentHeight = jqEvent.originalEvent.data.iframe;
        $('iframe').height(iframeContentHeight + 300);
    }
}
$(window).on('message.socialPanel', onMessage);
```

and here is the code inside the iframe (it is in an external file, let's call it **iframe.js**):

```
$(window).on('load', function () {
   var height = $('html').height();
   window.parent.postMessage({'iframe': height}, '*');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the solution (an explanation would be welcome though).

I had to put the iframe's javascript in an inline `<script>` tag and not in an external one.

So my previous code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/build.js" ></script>
```

has become:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function () {
                var height = $('html').height();
                window.parent.postMessage({'iframe': height}, '*');
            }
</script>
```

Comment: Maybe use $(document).ready() instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready

Comment: No, if I'm listening to load events it is because the page needs to be loaded... But thank you for taking time to answer...

Comment: @n00dl3 I have an idea of what is going on. If the iframe finishes loading its `src` before the parent executes `/assets/js/build.js`, the handler won't be attached before the `load` event, and thus won't fire. Moving the script inline must have made it execute earlier.

Comment: @Wiscocrew That would be relevant if the script was inside the parent window, but it was inside the iframe.

Answer (score 2):

another suggestion - `onload` is being triggered just once, yes, even when you change the `src` URL. But if you want it to be triggered again - just detach the iframe from DOM and attach it back again (when changing the URL). It did the trick for me.

Comment: this worked for us in ReactJS

Answer (score 1):

I ran into exactly the same problem. @n00dl3's solution might not work in all situations - it didn't for me. It's due to a race condition - the `load` handler needs to be attached before the `iframe` loads its `src`. In some cases, moving the JS inline would move it early enough, in my case it didn't.

Here's how I solved it:

1. Omit `src` and `onload` from the `iframe` tag:

```
<iframe id="foo"></iframe>
```

2. Define (in the parent document) the function I want to run on load:

```
function resize() {
  // do the resizing here
}
```

3. Again in the parent document, attach the `load` handler:

```
document.getElementById("foo").setAttribute("onload", "resize()");
```

4. Still in the parent document, set the `src`:

```
document.getElementById("foo").setAttribute("src", "https://example.com/bar");
```

Boom, fires every time.

Comment: I just want to memorialize, completely against SO decorum, that @Wiscocrew's rep as of the posting of this comment is 1337.